# how to get return value from a method of custom type using reflection?

Tags: c#, reflection

I have a method in class which returns a custom type. I am using reflection to invoke this method but not able to get the response.

NOTE: I cannot cast the return value to the custom type because I cannot refer the dll in my project.

```
Response = method.Invoke(instance, new[] { parameter});
```

`Response` is null now. this method call should return a custom type.

Answer (score 1):

You'll get the response as a `System.Object`:

```
object response = method.Invoke(instance, new[] { parameter });
```

There are multiple reasons you could still get `null` for response, including that the method itself returned `null` or it was a `void` method.